# Error on adding two cells using Excel-VBA for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to write my first code ever in Excel VBA for Mac. All I want to do is add two numbers. Sounds Hard, Right? I keep getting this error:

> Compile Error: invalid use of property.

Then a debugger window opens with the first line highlighted.

```
Sub abbas()
    'adds two numbers
    'from e2 and e3 and puts the result in e4
    Sheets("SHEET 1").Select
    Range("e2").Select
    A = ActiveCell.Value
    Range("e3").Select
    B = ActiveCell.Value
    Range("e4").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = A + B
    Range ("e5")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Error

The error is raised by the line
`Range ("e5")`
You did not associate any action with this range. You want to select it? You want to clear it? Compiler doesn't understand.

## Proposition of changed code

I'll propose you a 2 simplified codes with no errors

### Code 1

`Sub abbas()
    'adds two numbers
    'from e2 and e3 and puts the result in e4
    With Sheets("SHEET 1")
        A = .Range("e2")
        B = .Range("e3")
        .Range("e4") = A + B
    End With
End Sub`

### Code 2

```
 Sub abbas2()
    'adds two numbers
    'from e2 and e3 and puts the result in e4
    With Sheets("SHEET 1")
        .Range("e4") = .Range("e2") + .Range("e3")
    End With
End Sub
```

---

## Notes

Try to avoid lines with `Select` and `Activate`, you don't need them, you can refer to the values on worksheets directly as shown in my example codes.
It is a good practice to [Declare your variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx) on the top of the sub/function.
Consider making this sub a function. [Difference between the two](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html)